# Why console.log(window) works but JSON.stringify(window) doesn't work, and how can I beat that?

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

If I type in console:

```
 console.log(window)
```

I get all the objects in `window` with expand buttons.

But if I try the same with:

```
JSON.stringify(window)
```

I get in Firefox:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toJSON'
```

And in chrome:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Is this the only case where this happen? And given that `console.log()` and `JSON.stringify()` work differently, can I access and still stringify objects that `console.log()` manages to display?

Comment: Only a subset of possible JavaScript objects can be serialized as JSON. DOM nodes are not native JavaScript objects.

Comment: `var x = {}; x.x = x; JSON.stringify(x)`

Comment: @SLaks console.log(x) works but you can expand x in x too many times to try to see if it ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `window` has circular references (for instance, in most cases `window.self` refers to `window`) and then it cannot be converted to JSON, otherwise it would turn into an infinite loop.

This may happen on any object, not only on `window`:

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'bar'
};
JSON.stringify(foo);    // works fine

var foo = {
    bar: foo
};
JSON.stringify(foo);    // circular reference -> crashes
```

Comment: `var foo = { bar: foo }; JSON.stringify(foo);` does not crash for me in Chrome.

Comment: That's because Chrome has added a feature to avoid circular references in JSON objects during their stringifing process.